# Yii: default sort model by related table

Tags: php, yii

I have a three tables, "pets", "species" and "homes." Homes have multiple pets, each of which has a species. The species can be mixed in a home.

Is it possible to use `findByPk()` on a house and have the associated pets sorted by species then name?

```
Hendersons
--------------
Cat "Hairball"
Cat "Princess"
Dog "Ace"
Dog "Killer"
```

This is probably blindingly obvious to someone, but I'm not finding an answer.

Comment: yes is posible you can with the [relational query options](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-options)

Comment: Yep. That's it. Thanks. There a reason you didn't just submit that as an answer? Because I have the functional code and I'd like to attach it to the question, but I don't want to steal your internet points.

Comment: Don't worry, show this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Carlos' help, here's the functional code, in "homes" model:

```
'pets' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Pets', 'home_id',
                'order'=>'species.name ASC',
                'with'=>'species')
```

Pretty simple. Thanks, Carlos.